# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular, lambda, cors, xmlhttprequest, serverless

I am making an angular application which make a post request to an 
    AWS API gateway which invoke then a Lambda function , kindly note that I 
    adjusted the CORS settings in the AWS API GATEWAY and there is nothing 
    expected as header except 'Acessc-Control-Allow-Origin'

Below is my CODE and my Error

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



const body = {
  "body": "query{product(name:\"CIB\"){high}}"
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-tiles',
  templateUrl: './grid-tiles.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-tiles.page.scss'],
})
export class GridTilesPage implements OnInit {



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   httpdata;
   ngOnInit() {
      this.http.post("https://3ra64ngnc2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/test",body,{ 
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "POST" ,

        })      
      })
      .subscribe((data) => this.displaydata(data));     
   }
   displaydata(data) {this.httpdata = data;}
}
```

This is the error generated by the console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://3ra64ngnc2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Did you try to change it to - `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`? On another note, generally the CORS is blocked by browser so there are extensions in chrome which can be installed and therefore CORS requests are not blocked by browser anymore.

Comment: yes i tried to make "*" instead of "POST" and I faced the same error , however could you tell me what extension which can unblock it ?

Comment: just search in browser - Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin and add extension to chrome

Answer (score 0):

I passed the same issue a couple of hour ago.

This helped:
URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#how-to-cors-console
Enable CORS on a Resource Using the API Gateway Console, point #4.

And here is my Angular code. (Note i used the http.get)

```
 const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'x-api-key': 'my api key'
     })
};


private batteriesURL: string = 'https....my URL';

getAllBatteries(): Observable<any[]> {
     return this.http.get<any[]>(this.batteriesURL, httpOptions).pipe(
         tap(data => JSON.stringify(data)),
         catchError(this.handleError)
);}
```

The last thing we had to do was to update php code on PHP to allow CORS, and then CORB.

Hope this helps.